# insert series into postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, series

I want to insert a series of numbers in a postgreSQL column.The series will be

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3.....30
```

So 1-30 repeated 10 times each(300 rows).but I know to generate series I can use

```
 SELECT a.n
from generate_series(1, 100) as a(n), generate_series(1, 3)
```

How to insert this series into an existing table **public.trip** and to the column **day**.I tried with

`update public.trip
    set day = generate_series(1, 30) , generate_series(1, 10);`

But this is showing as an error.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: I wanted  this because I have to cook some dummy data.So I am not using this practice for real.Just to cook to some dummy data.Anyways thanks for sharing the knowledge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are inserting it as new data then you should use an INSERT INTO statement i this case it will be (I am assuming a.n is where the value of day is contained)

```
INSERT INTO public.trip(Day)
   SELECT a.n from generate_series(1, 100) as a(n), generate_series(1, 3)
```

if you are updating an existing record then you can use the UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE public.trip SET Day =  SELECT a.n from generate_series(1, 100) as a(n), generate_series(1, 3) WHERE [condition]
```

I hope this help

Comment: Ya this was helpful :)